# What happens if there is not enough crypto money to fulfill a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

Let's say a smart contract says: "In 365 days, X should send 0.005 Crypto to Y".

If the D-day X doesn't own enough Crypto to fulfill the contract, what will happen?

Comment: The contract can not dictate what X is doing unless X itself is a contract and the first contract has permission to control X. Typically, if the contract should enforce a particular transaction at a specific time, X would send 0.005 Crypto to the contract in advance and the contract would then send it to Y in 365 days

Comment: Ok, how should I proceed with a fundraising campaign? I thought I could warranty the payment with a smart contract, but I can not pay in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your smart contract cannot force this

> "In 365 days, X should send 0.005 Crypto to Y"

but X could allow the smart contract to do the transfer on behalf of X. so after 365 days, the smart contract will transfer "0.005 Crypto to Y" from X. if both tokens are `erc20` tokens.

If X does not have enough coins, that transfer will fail and you should handle the case accordingly